# Create multiple User classes programmatically

Tags: c#, list, class

First off I have this which foreach loop that goes through a dictionary of users. The 'int' value is a list of orders("ControlNumber").

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> e in errorOrders)
        {
            //finds error percentage for user
           errPercentage = GetErrPercentage(e.Key);
           Console.WriteLine("Percentage of errors for " + e.Key + ": " + Math.Round(errPercentage, 2) * 100 + "%");
            //finds orderPerHour for user
           ordersPerHour = OrdersPerHour(e.Key);
            //Selects random orders for user based on errPercentage, saves to DT "randomOrders"
           RandomOrders = RandomSelect(errPercentage, e.Key);

           Console.WriteLine("Number of orders pulled : " + RandomOrders.Rows.Count);
           //Print out orders randomly collected
           for (int i = 0; i < RandomOrders.Rows.Count; i++)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(RandomOrders.Rows[i]["ControlNumber"]);
           }

           Console.WriteLine("\r\n");

            //Creates class and fills class for each user
           FillUserListClass(RandomOrders);

         }
```

The part below is the FillUserListClass function. This is where my trouble occurs. Right now, 
I'm recieving an error ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object.") at the very last line of the function below. Where it tries to add the "ControlNumber" to the UserList[username] class.

Now, i'm open to suggestions on changing this function. Essentially, i want to create a Class for each user and held within this class would be a List containing each user's "ControlNumbers".

I had someone try to do this with LINQ but since that stuff waaay over my head, i couldn't troubleshoot it. (if you think that is the best way to go, i'll put the LINQ code up here also)

```
public static void FillUserListClass(DataTable dt)
    {
       Dictionary<string, List<int>> UserList = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

        {


            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                object value = row["ControlNumber"];
                if (value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    row.Delete();
                }
            }
            for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= dt.Rows.Count; ctr++)
            {
                var row = dt.Rows[ctr];
                var userName = row["User"].ToString();

                if (UserList.ContainsKey(userName))
                {
                    UserList[userName].Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["ControlNumber"]));
                }
                else
                {
                    UserList.Add(row["User"].ToString(), null);
                    UserList[userName].Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["ControlNumber"]));
                }
            }
}
```

In case you need it, here is my User class that I want to fill

```
 public class User
{
    private string _name;

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public List<int?> ControlNumber { get; set; }

   public User (string username)
   {
       _name = username;
   }

   public User()
   {
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing this error because you inserted a `null` value for a `List<int>` in the dictionary and then immediately tried to add an item to it.

Try replacing this

```
UserList.Add(row["User"].ToString(), null);
UserList[userName].Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["ControlNumber"]));
```

With this:

```
UserList.Add(userName, new List<int>());
UserList[userName].Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["ControlNumber"]));
```

Or even better:

```
UserList.Add(userName, new List<int>() { Convert.ToInt32(row["ControlNumber"]) });
```